# Do wages limit amount of deductions in year with very high capital gains

Tags: real-estate, tax-deduction, capital-gains-tax

Does my income from wages (24K) limit the itemized deductions I can take when my total income is mostly from Cap Gains earned from selling a longterm rental property  (200K after accounting for base and improvements)? I have much more than 24 k in itemized deductions not related to the sale of the property. This is a one time only situation.

Thank you - I look forward to hearing from you

Comment: you need to specify a country for tax questions

Comment: We look forward to you specifying your country. :)